# Is the Minecraft protocol between servers and clients based on any standard?

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers, minecraft

#### TL;DR

I'm trying to talk to a Minecraft server with a client written in Scala, using Akka I/O over TCP, and would like to know if Minecraft uses an official, standardised protocol in it's network communication?

[Minecraft's own documentation](http://wiki.vg/Protocol) covers the contents of each packet, but fails to explain how the packets themselves are encoded, or even how they should be formed.

---

#### A little back story

As part of a personal project that I'm working on, written in Scala, I need to create an interface capable of mocking a Minecraft client, and performing actions against a Minecraft server. After weeks of research, I came across a lot of Java libraries that were almost what I was looking for, but none that quite suited my exact needs; long story short, I did the classic, "Oh well, why not write it myself and enjoy the learning curve"...

#### The issue

[The Minecraft protocol documentation](http://wiki.vg/Protocol) is thorough in some respects, but lacking in others, many assumptions are made throughout and a lot of key information is missing or even incorrect; a detailed network specification being the most notable in my case.

One attempt to talk to the Minecraft server had me playing around with Google's protocol buffers, using [ScalaPB](https://github.com/scalapb/ScalaPB) to compile them to usable case classes, but the data types were a pain to resolve between Google's own documentation and Minecraft's.

```
message Handshake {
    <type?> protocolVersion = 1;
    <type?> host = 2;
    <type?> port = 3;
    <type?> nextState = 4;
}
```

The `host` is a string, so that's an easy win, but both the `protocolVersion` and `nextState` are variable integers, which are not encoded as expected when I compared them with valid packets generated by another client with identical contents (I've been using a third-party library to compare the hexadecimal output of encoded packets).

#### My hacky solution

In a ditch attempt to achieve my goals, I've simply written methods like the one below (this is also a first iteration, so be kind!) to generate the desired encoding for each of the types declared in Minecraft's documentation that are not supported natively in Scala, and although this works, it just smells like I'm missing something potentially obvious that others might know about.

```
def toVarint(x: Int): Array[Byte] = {
  var number = x
  var output = ArrayBuffer[Int]()

  while (number >= Math.pow(2, 31)) {
    output += number & 0xFF | 0x80
    number /= 128
  }

  while ((number & ~0x7F) > 0) {
    output += number  0xFF | 0x80
    number >>>= 7
  }

  output += number | 0

  output.map(_.toByte).toArray
}
```

Comment: Have you tried connecting with a regular minecraft client and recorded any packets send to the server?

Comment: I've had `tcpdump` following a real client, yes, and also the third-party client too, the payloads are pretty much the same. It creates a lot of noise to sift through though, which is why I use the hex strings from the third-party client instead, it's a lot quicker that way!

Answer (score 1):

This is old, but I'll answer anyway! [The wiki you referenced](https://wiki.vg/Protocol) has (at least now) a section on the packet format (both before & after compression), as well as explanations including example code for how to handle their varint & varlong types!

To summarise, each packet is length prefixed with a varint (in both compression modes), so you just need to read a varint from the stream, allocate that much space & read that many bytes from the stream to the buffer.

Each byte of Minecraft varints have a "another byte to follow?" flag bit, followed by 7 bits of actual data. Where those 7 bits are just the bits from a standard int (so on receive, you essentially just omit those flag bits & write the rest to a standard int type)